# Laravel 9 SymfonyMailer error - An email must have a "To", "Cc", or "Bcc" header

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail, symfony-mailer, laravel-9

I've got problems with sending emails after updating a Laravel 8 project using the Metronic 8 theme to Laravel 9. I didn't change any of my code related to emails, but now I got this error using the Sendmail driver :

> An email must have a "To", "Cc", or "Bcc" header.
> {"userId":6,"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\LogicException(code: 0): An
> email must have a "To", "Cc", or "Bcc" header. at
> /home/myhome/public_html/myproject.com/vendor/symfony/mime/Message.php:128)

**Controller**

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function activate($id)
    {
        $mymodel = MyModel::find($id);

        $contact = Contact::where('mymodel_id', $mymodel->id)->first();
        Mail::to($contact->email)->send(new MyMail($contact));
    }
}
```

**Mailable**

```
class MailActive extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $contact;

    public function __construct(Contact $contact)
    {
        $this->contact = $contact;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('theemail@gmail.com', 'Me')
            ->view('emails.myemailview')
            ->with([
                'contact' => $this->contact
            ]);

        // $this->withSymfonyMessage(function (Email $message) {
        //     $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
        //         'addAddress', 'theemail@gmail.com'
        //     );
        // });

        // return $this;
    }
}
```

I've tried to render the mail alone, and it works. Using the log driver, it works, and as you can see, I even tried to bypass the Mail facade using the withSymfonyMessage method in the mailable class, but nothing works.

Is there a config or a part I'm missing? Could I go back using SwiftMailer without much trouble for Laravel 9 to work?

Comment: In your upgrade process can you install these packages?
`composer require symfony/mailgun-mailer symfony/http-client`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? As far as I see, you are not setting any receiver in the given code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use **->to()**

```
return $this->from('theemail@gmail.com', 'Me')
            ->to($email, $name)
            ->view('emails.myemailview')
            ->with([
                'contact' => $this->contact
            ]);
```

Comment: It works like that yes ! The Mail facade doesn't take the to() anymore and we have to specify the address in the Mailable class ?

Comment: I am using Laravel 10. where to include this snippet ? I don't have any `build()`

Answer (score 1):

> An email must have a "To", "Cc", or "Bcc" header. {"userId":6,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\LogicException(code: 0): An email must have a "To", "Cc", or "Bcc" header. at /home/myhome/public_html/myproject.com/vendor/symfony/mime/Message.php:128)

You will get the above exception if `to()` is missing or if the `to()` method receive an empty collection in your Mailable class

Answer (score 1):

I am using Laravel 10+ and doing just this while calling `Mail` facade, worked for me:

`\Mail::to('to@example.com')->send(new MyMailableClass());`

P.S. I am using [MailTrap](https://mailtrap.io/) to test my emails for this.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

to() mail address is null given or cache issue

**cache issue:**
php artisan optimize:cl
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:cl

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that this is a caching issue?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

go to .env file and just add:

MAIL_TO_ADDRESS="example@gmail.com"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Shouldn't the mail be sent to a varying mail address instead of a static one?